# Swift updating barButtonItems for a view embedded in a tabBarController in a navigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

Basically I want to set up a barbutton item in my `HomeViewController` but it's not showing up. I am thinking it might have something to do with my navigation hierarchy. Here is my code for the `HomeViewController`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    backBtn = UIBarButtonItem(title: "< Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: Selector("goBack"))
    self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(backBtn, animated: true)
}
```

Here is a screenshot of my storyboard. I dynamically push a login screen on `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` when not logged in, which is why the `UITabBarController` is embedded inside the `UINavigationController` and not the other way around:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to embed HomeViewController into UINavigationController, which itself is one of UITabVarController's viewControllers array?

Comment: The problem with doing that is that it screws up the layout. I get a weird double navigation controller thing. Although I might be able to hide the first navcontroller's navbar. Maybe that would take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try with following `Navigation` flow.

You must need to set `ViewControllers` of `UITabbar` which are embedded in `UINavigationController`

Please refer following image for `Storyboard`.

[image]